# cant check if a div is fadeout and not clicked or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

guys i have a div that falls randomly and fadeout at the bottom of screen and when i click on it before reaching the bottom it will disappear .. so i want to calculate the number of missed divs that reaches the bottom and not clicked .. here is my code

```js
var ranInterval = 1000 + Math.floor((Math.random() * 7000) + 1);
window.setTimeout( CreateDiv, ranInterval ); 
function CreateDiv()
{
    var ranLeft1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 700) + 1);
    var ranInterval = 2000 + Math.floor((Math.random() *  5000) + 1);
    jQuery('<div class="droper1" id="droper1" onclick="myFunction1()"/>').css({top: 10, left: ranLeft1 }).
     animate({top: "+=583px"}, 9000 ).fadeOut(500).appendTo('#container' );

}

$(document).on("click", ".droper1", function(){
   score++;
   jQuery(this).remove();
   document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
  // checking if it is not clicked and fadeout increase the  missed variable 
});
```

```html
<td>Missed Green Boxes :</td>
<td><label type="text" id="missed" name="missed"></td> 
  
<div id="container" class="container"></div>
```

Comment: `id`'s should be unique. you are giving all divs the same `id`

Comment: I don't see any falling or fading divs in your code snippet.

Comment: Working fiddle for SO. Just wait around 7 seconds. http://jsfiddle.net/n3j1nupk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the answer to your question: http://jsfiddle.net/n3j1nupk/1/

```
var score = 0;
var misses = 0;
var ranInterval = 1000 + Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);
window.setTimeout( CreateDiv, ranInterval ); 
function CreateDiv()
{

    var ranLeft1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 700) + 1);
    var ranInterval = 2000 + Math.floor((Math.random() *  2000) + 1);
    jQuery('<div class="droper1" />').css({top: 10, left: ranLeft1 }).
    animate({top: "+=583px"}, 9000, 
        function() {
            if (!$(this).hasClass("clicked")) {
                misses++;
                document.getElementById("misses").innerHTML = "Misses: " + misses;
            }
        }).fadeOut(500).appendTo('#container' );
}

$(document).on("click", ".droper1", function(){
   score++;
    $(this).addClass("clicked");
   jQuery(this).remove();
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Score: " + score;
  // checking if it is not clicked and fadeout increase the  missed variable 
});
```

When you click a square you add a class to it. When it reaches the bottom you check if has that class, if not it means it's not been clicked.
Please note that your code has something else that's not working (only one cube spawns), but that's beyond the scope of this question.